# Android Capture Video and play

Tags: android, android-videoview

I want my application to Record a video and play on VideView in android. I am doing this for that.

```
Intent takeVideoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
context.startActivityForResult(takeVideoIntent, ACTION_TAKE_VIDEO);
```

// context is an Activity's context

And overriding onActivityResult() as

```
Uri mVideoUri = data.getData();
videoView.setVideoUri(mVideoUri);
videoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
videoView.requestFocus();
```

But Its not playing the recorded video, I also tried by using

```
videoView.setVideoPath(mVideoUri.getPath());
```

instead of Uri, but nothing happened except one change that, it show this video cannot be played.

Comment: Post the logcat output. That way people can help you out by nailing the error easily rather than spend most of their time speculating on problems you may be having.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue, i just made a silly mistake that i didn't invoke videoView.start() Method.